# Creating a particle using an image as a map

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having trouble creating a particle using an image as a map on a texture. Below is my code:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, material, img, texture;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 8000;
  scene.add(camera);

  img = new Image();
  texture = new THREE.Texture(img);

  img.onload = function() {
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    makeParticle();
  };
  img.src = "http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/images/particle.png";

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function makeParticle() {
  material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xE60000,
    size: 20,
    map: texture,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
  });
  // make the particle
  particle = new THREE.Particle(material);
  particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 1;
  scene.add(particle);
}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

A fiddle with this code is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/zUvsp/23/)

I am aware I can use the Three Image Helper as follows:

```
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
  "FILE PATH"
),
```

But I am implementing my own asset loader and so do not wish to use it on an individual basis. Currently my code above shows no errors but no particle is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle is being displayed, but the camera is very far of it.

Change this line:

```
camera.position.z = 8000;
```

To something like this:

```
camera.position.z = 50;
```